# Redirecting a subdomain from wordpress.com to an external web address

Tags: wordpress, redirects, url, subdomain

I have a question about redirecting a subdomain of a blog hosted on `wordpress.com` to an external URL.

Given the following:

1) I own a domain name `foobar.com` purchased from another registrar (not from `wordpress.com`).

2) I have purchased the custom domain option on `wordpress.com`, and have completed the configuration to make `foobar.com` resolve to `foobar.wordpress.com`.

3) I will establish an external site for a store, such as `store.yahoo.com/foobar`.

4) I want to redirect the subdomain `store.foobar.com` to `store.yahoo.com/foobar`.

How do I set up the custom DNS records within `wordpress.com` to accomplish this subdomain redirection, while leaving `foobar.com` pointed to my Wordpress blog? I suspect that the CNAME directive is involved, but I cannot figure out the required syntax.

Comment: Who provides the DNS service for your domain, Wordpress or your domain registrar?

Comment: The DNS service is provided by Wordpress.com. They have an interface on the site that allows a blog owner to input custom DNS records, as explained [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/custom-dns/).

Answer (score 1):

A CNAME DNS record will not perform a redirect.  It will simply just cause the HTTP request to go to store.yahoo.com (if that is the object of the CNAME record) containing the HTTP header:

```
    Host: store.foobar.com
```

Which Yahoo will not know how to process.

From the link you provided, Wordpress doesn't appear to offer a GUI redirect feature as a part of their DNS service.  You may want to consider using your domain registrar's DNS service for this domain.  That's what I do.  My registrar is GoDaddy and they have an easy to use DNS manager that I use to create similar redirects.

If you need to keep your DNS with Wordpress, you need to have Wordpress configured to accept a request for `store.foorbar.com` and then in your Wordpress site, redirect that request to `store.yahoo.com/foobar`.

I will do more research to see how to accomplish that.

Comment: John... Thanks for the response. I'm not certain that the domain registrar I am using has the capabilities you describe. I'll look into that. Given that I've already paid for the custom DNS option, I'd prefer to do this within the Wordpress custom DNS framework.